# Item in list doesn't get iterated

Tags: python

I have a list of strings where string that start in lowercase should be removed and I made this code

```
def remove_names(name_list):
    for i in name_list:
        print(i[0])
        if i[0].islower():
            name_list.remove(i)

countries_list = ["New Zealand", "germany", "australia", "Canada", "China"]
remove_names(countries_list)
print(countries_list)
```

for some reason the string `"australia"` doesn't get iterated, any reasons why?

Comment: oh i already fixed my code but i believe my answer is in that question

Comment: Glad to hear it! If they helped you then please upvote the question and answer so future users find them faster!